# Get Data from Gridview to Checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a windows applicatin in c#
and i want to retrive value from gridview to checklist box on gridview cell click and value has been checked in checkbox
help me idont know how to do..

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Comment: Consider researching data binding:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
private void yourGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
{
 yourCheckListBox.Items.Add(yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
}
}
```

You can reference how to add data to checkBoxList [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss.aspx) !

OR try this one ,

```
   private void yourGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
{
 string selectedValue =yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
 yourCheckListBox.Items.Add(new BindingList<Binder> { new Binder { Name = selectedValue } });
yourCheckListBox.Invalidate();  
yourCheckListBox.Update();  
yourCheckListBox.Refresh();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i want a code for get value from gridview to checklistbox on gridview cell click event...                        So can you gave me code for that????

Comment: yourCheckListBox.Items.Add(yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();                                               In this line cells[e.columnindex] you write and i have to write my column name???

Comment: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set. I got error like this...

Comment: No , no need to write your column name , just use `e.ColumnIndex` . It's will return your selected cell's index :)

Comment: I got an error like "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set".

Comment: Look yourCheckListBox's Property . did you set yourCheckListBox's datasource ?Just Remove it !

Comment: try `string value = yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();` , if you get value correctly , follow the link that i added in my answer :)

Comment: k my checklist box has been bound and i want that if i click on any column data then it recieve me correct value of that field...